Blender to Aftereffects - EXR-multilayer with AGX Color profile workflow
I havebeen trying to render all required into EXR Multilayer and composite inside Aftereffects, But the problem is EXR inside after effects with AGX color profile not looking as good as PNG output. I am missing out some color convertion steps. Please help here who have found solution for this. I am facing issue for AGX color workflow.
Thanks.
